# What thing I need to done when I need to store more information in lucence.net index?

Tags: search, indexing, lucene.net

In Lucene  I need to add some information about the post for search. For make a better search I thing to add the tags name or some other information to  make a bettter search. What option I choose whenever I have two possible option for solve this problem.

Append the tags into the content or excerpt of the post I have.

Or make a new index to solve the same puzzle.

Well I need to know what is different if  I append them in existing index or make a new index in lucene to store an another kind of information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add your tags to a separate tokenised `tag` field.

A typical query would look something like this:

```
content:(+honda +civic) +tag:red +tag:hatchback
```

The first two terms (`honda` and `civic`) are entered by the user, while the second two terms (`red` and `hatchback`) would be selected from a list of tags.

If you want to support tags that contain spaces, you will have to roll your own tokeniser by subclassing `CharTokenizer`: [Lucene.Net support phrases?: What is best approach to tokenize comma-delimited data (atomically) in fields during indexing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447139)

```
+tag:"5 door"
```

You can create a separate index for your `tag` field, but you will have to use a `MultiSearcher` to perform a combined search of the separated indexes.